# Nuxt.js - console.log build version

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm hosting a Nuxt site on AWS S3 w/ Cloudfront, so when deploying I need to invalidate the CloudFront CDN.  This means it takes a bit for the deploy to

I'd like to `console.log(buildHash)` when the application starts.  What's the best way to do this?

I could add this to a plugin, but what's the best way to get the build hash?

There is a manifest.xxx.js file which seems to hold build hashes of the other files in the project.  Is that manifest hash unique for each unique build?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a tumbleweed.  Here's what I did:

A plugin to print the manifest hash:

````
```
// Statup and small stuff
window.onNuxtReady(() => {
  // Print build version of this script
  var scripts = window.document.getElementsByTagName('script')
  for (var i=0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    // Get the script name
    var src = scripts[i].src
    src = src.substr(src.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
    if (src && src.startsWith('manifest')) console.log('Hello ' + src)
  }
})

```
````

Added to `nuxt.config.js`

````
```
  plugins: [
    'plugins/bootstrap-vue.js',
    'plugins/scroll.js',
    { ssr: false, src: '~plugins/etc.js' },
  ]
```
````